# How to call a Matlab CPLEX program from Python

Tags: python, matlab, integration, cplex

I have already written a program on distribution network planning in Matlab to find the optimal solution through CPLEX. Now I want to package the M-file function through Python package in library compiler function in Matlab and call the script through Python.

What I have done so far is to install `H:\wenti3\for_redistribution_files_only` via cmd with python setup.py install and the program runs successfully in Matlab, but fails in Python.

Matlab program:

```
function P = wenti3()
    clc;
    clear;
    %% 三个时间段  三台机组
    a = [0.001562,0.00194,0.005784];
    b = [7.92,7.85,9.56];
    c = [561,310,93.6];
    load = [650,1000,700];
    Pmin = [150 100 50];
    Pmax = [600 400 200];
    J = 3; % 机组数量
    T = 3; % 时间段
    %% 定义未知量
    P = sdpvar(J,T,'full'); % 定义矩阵必须加 'full'
    ccost = sdpvar(J,T,'full');
    for t = 1:T
        for j =1:J
        ccost(j,t) = a(j).*P(j,t).^2 + b(j).*P(j,t) + c(j) ;
        end
    end
    CCOST = sum(sum(ccost));
    %% 建立约束
    cons = [];
    for t = 1:T
     cons = [cons , sum(P(:,t)) == load(t)]; %负荷需求相等
    end 
    for t = 1:T
        for j =1:J
       cons = [cons , P(j,t) >=  Pmin(j) ];
       cons = [cons , P(j,t) <=  Pmax(j) ];
    %    cons = [cons , Pmin(j) <= P(j,t) <=  Pmax(j)  ];
       end
    end
    %% 爬坡约束
    for t = 2:T
        for j =1:J
          cons = [ cons , P(j,t) - P(j,t-1) >= - 0.3*Pmax(j)];
          cons = [ cons , P(j,t) - P(j,t-1) <=  0.3*Pmax(j)];
    %     cons = [ cons , - 0.3*Pmax(j) <= P(j,t) - P(j,t-1) <=  0.3*Pmax(j)];
        end
    end
    %% 设置求解器参数
    options = sdpsettings('verbose',0,'solver' ,'cplex');
    % ops.cplex.mip.tolerance.mipgap = 0.001 ;
    options.showprogress = 0;

    yalmip_message = optimize(cons, CCOST );
    disp( yalmip_message );
    %% 输出结果
    pp = P;
    P = value(P) ;
end
```

---

Python call code:

```
import wenti3

mat_obj = wenti3.initialize()
result1 = mat_obj.wenti3()
```

The `result1` variable should be the return value `P` in the Matlab function, but running it in Python results in:
`matlab.double([[nan,nan,nan],[nan,nan,nan],[nan,nan,nan]])`. The expected result should be:

```
ans =

320.0000 500.0000 350.0857
280.0000 400.0000 299.9143
 50.0000 100.0000  50.0000
```

What should I do to make the Python call to CPLEX work?

[image: screen shot]

[image: another screen shot]

[image: yet another screen shot]

[image: and one more screen shot]

Comment: matlab version is 2018a , CPLEX is 12.8.0 python version is 3.6

Comment: Due to more CPELX modeling using Matlab and my unfamiliarity with the syntax of how to use cplex in python

Comment: My guess is that CPLEX is an external library, with a series of M-files or MEX-files as interface to MATLAB. The MATLAB compiler includes those M- or MEX-files in your bundle, but not the external library. When running it, the MATLAB runtime is not able to link to that external library, and so you get NaNs as output. This is just a guess, but hopefully it's a place for you to start looking for the problem. Good luck!